# Simple and Quick FTPS Site testing needed

Tags: .net, windows, ftps

I've got an FTPS site that I need to transfer a file to each night.  My problem is that the site is hosted at a contractor's site (Contractor A) and the SSIS package that sends the file to the site was created/maintained by a another contractor (Contractor B).

My problem is that the file transfer isn't happening.  Each of my contractors is blaming the other for the problem and it's left to me to determine the problem.  Contractor B says that his SSIS package works only during the day while testing, but can not connect at night when it needs to.  Contractor A claims that there is nothing changing with the FTPS site that would cause that.

I can create a .NET service to do this, but was hoping for a simplier solution. I was going to create a windows task that would execute a bat file every 5 minutes, and use the MS ftp client.  However, I can't get this to work with the FTPS.  I also couldn't get the User Name and PW sent with the url.  Any help here would be appreciated. I've been on Google all morning and have found multiple examples that almost work, but nothing that gets me all the way there.

Any simple command line test that uses Explicit FTP over TLS and allows passing a user name and pw is  all that is needed.

Comment: Have you already done a manual file transfer (using whatever client application program) to confirm that "Explicit FTP over TLS" works from your site to Contractor A's site? I'm thinking that before making any attempts at automation you should make sure you're not going down some rabbit-hole of issues such as authentication, group policy, firewalls, DPI, or whatever.

Comment: It's also kinda funny that Contractor B seems to be saying that things work during the day but not at night. Maybe a manual file transfer should be done at night to at least confirm that it works?

Comment: I have done a manual file transfer using FileZilla.  Fails periodically using implicit FTP, but Explict works always.  Last night, we ran some tests between 2 and 3 am. All worked.  So it appears as if FTP through our SSIS package is failing, but again, only when run over night.

Comment: OK, then - when the SSIS fails, does it at least "know" that it failed (error message in a log or whatever)? Or does it "think" that it's a success? I'm wondering if there's some sort of timeout issue going on - anything to explain the success-at-day vs fail-at-night.

Comment: The exception the contractor is reporting is, 'Site unavailable'

Comment: The most interesting aspect here appears to be: you say you found solutions but the did not work. So _why_ do you say they did not work? What happened? Wouldn't it make sense to get them to work?

Comment: Is this seems a job for Wireshark.

Comment: @arkascha  I'm not sure what solutions you are referring to?  We can connect via Filezilla using an implicit connection.  When we use the SSIS package, it works during the day but fails during the scheduled execution with a connection failed error.  I would like to test this on my own. I don't have access to SSIS and Filezilla can't be automated, so I want a script that can simulate the SSIS package, checking every 5 minutes with an implicit connection with credentials, just as the SSIS package does.

Comment: Understood that. Sure. But you wrote in your question: `on Google all morning and have found multiple examples that almost work, but ...`. That is what I am referring to. What does 'almost work' mean? Where is the problem? Why couödn't you get those examples you found to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To periodically check if the service can be reached a simple telnet would be enough. You don't even have to speak ftp. If you really want to upload a file, then the simpliest would be to use an ftp command line client used by a script. The script can be in whatever language, it does not matter.

It might also be worth exploring the [checktls](http://www.checktls.com) service. It allows to test tls connections, you can click together a list of commands. In this case classical ftp commands like 'USER: someone' and 'PASS: somepass' and so on.

---

The Filezilla client offers to specify the usage of explicit or implicit tls. From the description at the [FileZilla Wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/SSL/TLS#Explicit_vs_Implicit_FTPS):

> Explicit vs Implicit FTPS
>
> FTPS (SSL/TLS) is served up in two incompatible modes. If using
> explicit FTPS, the client connects to the normal FTP port and
> explicitly switches into secure (SSL/TLS) mode with "AUTH TLS",
> whereas implicit FTPS is an older style service that assumes SSL/TLS
> mode right from the start of the connection (and normally listens on
> TCP port 990, rather than 21). In a FileZilla client this means
> prefixing the host with "FTPES://" to connect an "explicit" FTPS
> server, or "FTPS://" for the legacy "implicit" server (for which you
> will likely also need to set the port to 990).

---

And here is a cURL pased solution using phps cURL extension:

```
// $handle: the file to upload
$handle  = fopen ( $path, 'r' );
// $url: the ftps url to connect to (without credentials)
$url     = sprintf ( 'ftps://%s/%s', $server, $filename ); 
// the ftp connection
$session = curl_init ( ); 
// connection details
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, sprintf( '%s:%s', $user, $pass );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl_session, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle );
// execute the connection
$output = curl_exec  ( $session );
// check for errors
$error  = curl_errno ( $session );
// close connection
curl_close ( $session );
```

The advantage of this approach: you can automate it. For example call it as a cron job.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with explicit versus implicit FTPS, so it isn't just as simple as checking for the connection.  We need to test the connection as well as logging in with credentials.  We have found that explicit FTPS will fail intermittently, so we need to check Implicitly.

Comment: Sorry, but "will fail intermittently" sounds to me like it is an issue on the server side. Fix that server, I'd say. Or better: have it fixed (or replaced) by the one responsible for it.

Comment: Right, now you're seeing my problem. It isn't my server. The server belongs to a contractor who says there is not server problem. I think there is.  So, I want a way to test it so I can say, "I've been connecting all day but at 2 am it starts denying connections", or something like that.  Right now, he's blaming the contractor (another company) who created the SSIS package.

Comment: Ok, I understand that point. I just found the checktls service, added it to the answer. Might be worth a try...

Comment: Added a citation from the FileZilla Wiki about using FileZilla for explicit and implicit ftp.

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to get the FileZilla client app to work using an Implicit connection.  However, this doesn't mimic the unattended connection our SSIS package is doing so it's not a valid test. That's why I'm looking for something I can run unattended every 5 minutes or so. However, I can't find anything that supports the Implict connection with passed credentials.

Comment: Ok, if you want to automate things, then use a scripting approach. Gives you endless flexibility. I added an example of a cURL based approach using php syntax to the answer. The same logic is obviously available wherever you have cURL available.

Comment: I gave you the answer and the bounty just because I was going to loose the bounty anyway and I know you put a lot of effort into the answer. Hope you get it. Not sure how the bounty stuff works exactly. I ended up using WinSCP.

Comment: OK, great you found a solution at least. I did not receive the bounty, but that does not matter. It is just stupid points without meaning, who cares? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is [scriptable](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), even for [FTPS](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).